# Update fk with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys

My picture table with two OneToOne relations to the User table:

[image: ERD]

Picture entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pictures")
public class Picture implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = true)
    private User customer;

    public User getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(User customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "photographer_id", nullable = false)
    private User photographer;

    public User getPhotographer() {
        return photographer;
    }

    public void setPhotographer(User photographer) {
        this.photographer = photographer;
    }

    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    private BigDecimal price;

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    public Picture(String title,
                   String url,
                   BigDecimal price)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Picture() {
        // Empty constructor
    }
}
```

PictureDaoImpl:

```
@Override
public void insert(Picture object) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(object);
}
```

How can I update the two foreign keys `customer_id` and `photographer_id`?

In the entity the two foreign keys are OneToOne relations to `User`

The error I get is `Column 'photographer_id' cannot be null`

Answer (score 0):

**You made an extremely wrong DB design.**

Between DB entities you can't make two relations, between tables\entities
can be only and only single relation.

According to your design you need to relation of `@OneToMany` relation between `Picture` and `User`, for every single/one picture you have many users, even if da facto you'll eventually have only two users, because two are still not one/single, so it's being considered as Many.

I suggest that first do your redesign DB.